# Online render farms for blender

Tags: rendering

I wanted to ask if there are any free render farms. I tried to find one but I couldn’t. If anyone finds a “free” render farms pls tell me.

Comment: You can use foxrender farm . Upon signing up itself you will get 25$ free credit. The cost per frame is very low too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sheep it is free to use. Your projects will be prioritized if you have enough "credits", which you obtain by sharing your CPU/GPU (that is, rendering other users projects), but that's not mandatory.

[Sheep it Renderfarm](https://www.sheepit-renderfarm.com/)

Comment: And you "pay" for your render time with the credits you earn rendering other people's renders.

Comment: Yes but if you don't have enough credits, your project will still render - it will just be at the end of the queue, so you will have to wait longer.

Comment: Thank you everyone. This is a great  community.